# Load Library is not loading when additional functions gets updated into the library

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, googletest

I am leading library from my `.exe`. When I am using `LoadLibrary("abc.dll")`, it loads the library. Now in `abc.dll`, I am doing some modification for `google-test`. I am trying to see the test case names by using

```
UnitTest& ptest; 
ptest.GetTestCase(i)->name()
```

When I am adding this peice of code, the `.dll` gets generated successfully but the `.dll` is not getting loaded by the `.exe` and the moment I am commenting above peiece of code then, `.dll` is getting loaded successfully.

I have added required `include files` and required `gtest.lib` files too.

Where exactly the problem is lieing?

Comment: is gtest.lib a static or a dynamic library? If it's a dynamic library, maybe gtest.dll is not found when LoadLibrary is called for abc.dll.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I just changed the Structure Member Allignment  to 1 Byte and things did work.

```
Project->propoties->C/C++->Code generation->Structure Member Allignment -> 1 Byte
```